# JuliaPro : ERROR: SystemError: unable to read directory Operation not permitted

Tags: julia, operation, system-error

JuliaPro - https://juliacomputing.com/products/juliapro/

I just get this Error with JuliaPro 1.5.2 - JupyterNote works fine -
MacBook Pro 2019 - Tried to uninstall and reinstall, but I'm not understanding why JuliaPro is giving me this error.

EDIT: Mac - Security & Privacy - Files and Folders - Atom all checked - JuliaPro-1.5.2.app - all checked

Full Disk Access - checked

Atom v0.12.23,
CSV v0.7.7,
DataFrames v0.21.8,
Glob v1.3.0,
IJulia v1.22.0,
JuliaDB v0.13.0,
Juno v0.8.4,
Pipe v1.3.0,
PkgAuthentication v0.3.0,
Weave v0.10.6,
Statistics

```
using Glob, CSV, Tables, DataFrames
fileDirectory = "/Users/Documents/CSV"

files = glob("*.csv", fileDirectory)

ERROR: SystemError: unable to read directory /Users/Documents/CSV: Operation not permitted
```

Stacktrace:
[1] readdir(::String; join::Bool, sort::Bool) at ./file.jl:780
[2] readdir at ./file.jl:775 [inlined]
[3] _glob!(::Array{String,1}, ::Glob.FilenameMatch{SubString{String}}) at /Users/.julia/packages/Glob/GOSfX/src/Glob.jl:399
[4] glob(::String, ::String) at /Users/.julia/packages/Glob/GOSfX/src/Glob.jl:367
[5] top-level scope at none:1

EDIT to Error: This shows up in Atom

Juno-julia-run

Argument to path.dirname must be a string

Object.dirname - /Applications/JuliaPro-1.5.2-1.app/Contents/MacOS/JuliaPro-Juno-1.5.2-1.app/Contents/Resources/JuliaPro-Juno-1.5.2-1/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/electron-shims.js:9:10
 - /Applications/JuliaPro-1.5.2-1.app/Contents/MacOS/JuliaPro-Juno-1.5.2-1.app/Contents/Resources/julia_atom_1.5.2-1/packages/JuliaRun-in-JuliaPro/lib/fs-utils.js:29:31
Generator.throw - null:null:null
step - /Applications/JuliaPro-1.5.2-1.app/Contents/MacOS/JuliaPro-Juno-1.5.2-1.app/Contents/Resources/julia_atom_1.5.2-1/packages/JuliaRun-in-JuliaPro/lib/fs-utils.js:41:273

Comment: Could it be just file permissions? What happens when you run `sudo julia` and then try to run this code in Julia terminal?

Comment: Side note, maybe the slanted double quotes are a problem? `julia> fileDirectory = “/Users/Documents/CSV”` errors for me.

Comment: @ Przemyslaw Szufel - thank you for the help - sudo: julia: command not found

Comment: @ Benoit Pasquier - thank you for the help - it's not slanted in the code (it maybe a font) it's a normal double quotes

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel in the Julia REPL sudo Julia - ERROR: syntax: extra token "julia" after end of expression

Comment: For sure `sudo julia` should work, pls read about the `sudo` command what it is and how it works https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202035